# Como importar arquivos CSV de uma pasta de mesmo nível (e/ou acima) em Python?

Tags: python, csv

Já busquei diversos tópicos aqui, sem sucesso entretanto. Assim, se já existe alguma pergunta igual, me perdoem e indiquem por favor uma solução. O meu projeto está articulado da seguinte maneira:

```
linuxServer # /
----bin
----data
    ----arquivoCsv.csv
----packages
    ----lib
        ----module
            ----module.py
__init.py__ 
main.py
```

A minha ideia é por meio do module.py, chamar o arquivoCsv.csv. Não consigo de maneira nenhuma executar o leitor csv dentro de module.py. Mas se eu testar no main.py ele funciona:

funcional:

```
#linuxServer/main.py
import csv

somelist = []
with open('data/arquivoCsv.csv', 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1')as csvFile:
    itens = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter =';')
    for line in itens:
        somelist.append(line)
```

Não funcional:

```
#linuxServer/package/lib/module/module.py

import csv

somelist = []
with open('linuxServer/data/arquivoCsv.csv', 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1')as csvFile:
    itens = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter =';')
    for line in itens:
        somelist.append(line)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'linuxServer/data/arquivoCsv.csv'
```

PS: dicas se a estrutura ta legal ou preciso mudar algo serão bem vindas.

Comment: vc tentou usar `'../data/arquivoCsv.csv'` ?? Na verdade `../../../`. Mas esta não seria a melhor opção. O `modulo.py` é importado pelo `main.py` ?

Comment: Já sim, Dá o mesmo erro:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/arquivoCsv.csv'

Sim, o modulo.py é importado em main.py

Comment: se esta com dificuldades no arquivo e esta usando um gnu/linux  abra o terminal na pasta que esta o csv e de um pwd para ele mostrar o caminho e cole no direcionamento da leitura do csv.. Ou dentro da pasta que esta os arquivos python coloque o csv.. ficando assim open('arquivoCsv.csv')

Comment: A questão é que não quero mudar nenhum arquivo de lugar. To no mac, dai o pdw não funciona

Answer (score -1):

No `main.py` faça algo como:

```
import os

diretorio_base = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  # ou use "." no lugar do `__file__`
diretorio_data = os.path.join(diretorio_base, "data")
```

Ao chamar a função que está em `modulo.py` passe o `diretorio_data` como parâmetro

Aí, é só fazer:

```
with open(os.path.join(PARAMETRO_RECEBIDO_PARA_DIRETORIO_DATA, 'arquivoCsv.csv'), 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1')as csvFile:
```

Comment: Deu certo assim:
dir_base = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('./linuxServer'))
dir_data = os.path.join(diretorio_base, "data")

e dai lá no with open, em vez de usar a vírgula, usei o + pra concatenar. A única dúvida é, sempre que eu precisar de um arquivo em outras pastas, vou precisar passar a pasta base e a que eu quero acessar como parâmetro? Não existe um jeito de sempre acessar diretamente?

Comment: Alguém pode dizer o porque votou negativo para que eu possa melhorar a resposta ?

Comment: @ÉricoPiantkoski , imagina que seu programa possa ser instalado por diferentes pessoas em diferentes diretórios. O ideal não é fixar o lugar que ele será instalado. Usando o os.path, você dará a oportunidade desta flexibilidade

Comment: Muito obrigado @PauloMarques ajudou demais